# Imagick setResolution() to read an Imagick object but not an empty Imagick object

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

Is there a way to read the resolution of a file not as an empty Imagick object?

We know from the manual that resolution should be set before reading a file but I realize that it works on empty Imagick object only.

Method for reading resolution of an empty Imagick object:

```
$im = new Imagick();
im->setResolution(300,300);
$im-> readimage($files);
```

My question is how to read the resolution of the following Imagick object?

```
$im = new Imagick($files);
```

In my application file path should be read as new `imagick object` but not as an `image` implied by `readimage();`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want the resolution of an empty object? Or the resolution of a list of files, all of which could be different? You want to *get* the resolution using `setResolution()`?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Not an empty object, I made that quiet clear in my example. Imagick should  read the resolution of a list of files as a new imagick object like `$im = new Imagick($files);`.  `$files` is an array here. Any idea shall be well appreciated.

Comment: `getImageResolution()` then?

Comment: @Mark Setchell `$im = new Imagick($files); $im ->getImageResolution(300,300);` doesn't make any difference. How to get the resolution correctly in this case? Thanks,

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but you aren't telling me anything new. Please read your question again - spellchecker may have changed something unexpectedly. You cannot **get** image resolution using **setResolution()**.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I get the expected output when I use `setResolution()` before reading an image in case of an empty imagick object like my example. I have no problem if `setImageResolution` does the task.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! the resolution is quite interesting.

To serve the purpose the `$files` array should be once defined as a `new Imagick();` object like `$im = new Imagick($files);` and then loop `$files` as an image like, `$im-> readimage($files);` after defining `setResolution();` to `$im-> readimage($files);` so that `readimage();` can read newly set reading resolution.

```
$im = new Imagick($files);
$im->setResolution(144, 144);
foreach ($myfiles as $files){   
$im->readimage($files);
}
```

However I asked `Mark Setchell` if  `setImageResolution();` does serve the same purpose as I was expecting his idea about it, although we know that `setImageResolution();` has no involvement to read the resolution of original file. it's actually `setResolution();` that does the job. `setImageResolution();` is used to set or redefine the resolution of an object that's already read by `setResolution();`